# arm gcc linker undefined reference

Tags: makefile, linker, arm, undefined-reference

I am working with this [code](https://github.com/rsta2/uspi) i found on github.
In order to use the uspi library,the help documentation(USING SECTION) said that i should create a makefile and specify the includes and libraries files there. 
Because i am new to makefile concept,i first try to manually do that by typing:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O0 -DRPI2 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -std=c99 -I./uspi/env/include -I./uspi/include -L./uspi/lib -luspi w.o -o kernel.elf
```

this errors comes up:

```
w.o: In function `main':
w.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `USPiEnvInitialize'
w.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `USPiInitialize'
w.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `USPiEnvClose'
w.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `USPiMassStorageDeviceAvailable'
w.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `USPiEnvClose'
w.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `USPiMassStorageDeviceRead'
w.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `LogWrite'
w.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `USPiEnvClose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i need the .elf file so i can generate a .img file from it

Comment: And if you add `-luspi` after `w.o` ? (Note that you need to implement functions declared in uspios.h yourself, such as LogWrite)

Comment: no luck my friend,same errors

Comment: I don't believe you. If you still get an undefined reference to e.g. USPiEnvClose, some thing else is wrong that we don't have any info about. Is the library itself properly built, (You'll get an undefined reference to LogWrite() until you implement  it though)

Comment: implement functions declared in uspios.h

Comment: do you mean implement the functions in 'w.c' program?

Comment: Sure. Wherever you like. The https://github.com/rsta2/uspi/blob/master/README.md notes that you somehow have to provide the functions in uspios.h. You're using a compiler targeting linux though, that might pull in the standard linux libc, which is not going to work in a bare metal application. (You should likely compile with the -ffreestanding flag or use a compiler for bare metal applications - , though that might result in more undefined references from usbios.h - you need to implement malloc/free etc. too)

Answer (score 1):

This link order:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ... -luspi w.o -o kernel.elf
```

is incorrect. Libraries should *follow* the objects they are referenced from:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ... w.o -luspi -o kernel.elf
```

[Explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).